# Activeadmin Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, nested-attributes

I have models products and gallery with has_many belongs_to relation, I'm implementing nested_attributes feature, Problem here is: When I click on add gallery two inner forms get created instead of one, as shown in below image:[image]

**CODE**

```
    form do |f|
    f.inputs "Product" do
        f.input :title, :required => true
        f.input :description
        f.input :price
        f.input :display_image
        f .input :product_detail, :hint => "Upload PDF file"
        f.input :category
    end

    f.inputs 'Product Gallery' do
        f.has_many :galleries, allow_destroy: true, new_record: 'Add Gallery' do |c|
            c.input :image, :hint => c.template.image_tag(c.object.image.url(:thumb)) 
        end
    end
    f.inputs 'Product Specification' do
        f.has_many :specifications, allow_destroy: true, new_record: true do |c|
            c.input :specification_label
            c.input :specification_details
        end
    end
    f.actions
end
```

I need help on this. I'm not able to solve this!!, any help would be appreciable.

Comment: I cannot see your code, but I encounter the same before, you should put the add fields link/button that generates dynamic fields, outside of the f.fields_for :galleries

Comment: Hi @aldrien.h thanks for  the reply, I'm not using f.fields_for anywhere in my code, I edited my question and added the code!

Comment: i think because you have two loops, that's why it generates twice.

Comment: did you added ` accepts_nested_attributes_for` in model?

Comment: what parameter are you permit in this form?

Comment: Yes @uzaif , I have added accepts_nested_attributes_for in model

Comment: can you show me full code of form?

Comment: In controller I have given access to these params galleries_attributes: [:id, :image]

Comment: I have updated my question @uzaif. Added full code of form.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
   f.inputs 'Product Gallery' do
      f.has_many :galleries do |c|
        c.input :image, :hint => c.template.image_tag(c.object.image.url(:thumb)) 
        c.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean
      end
    end
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering @hgsongra , I tried this but no luck.